# textarea hides the next element in jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

I am trying to design an email content dialog box shows like below:

```
header : text box
content : text area
go button(to submit)
```

The 'Go' button down to 'content' text area doesn't shows inside the dialog box. It is getting displayed outside the dialog box. When I am trying to place before text area it works fine. whatever(text, button etc) placed next to text area is getting displayed outside the dialog box. if i remove text area the 'go' button comes inside. i  increased the width of div also it doesn't work out please help me to resolve this issue. My piece of code is shown below.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="float:left;"><label>header:</label></div>
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input class="wideWidth" type="text" id="header_{0}" name="header_{0}" MaxLength="300" style="width:600px;" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div>
    <div style="float:left;">
      <label>content:</label>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
      <textarea id="emailbody_{0}" name="emailbody_{0}"style="width:600px;height:100px" value="" ></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" name="" class="btnGo" Value="Go" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the same?

Comment: Seems like all these code is inside an anothe <text area>. the problem is related to this?